# How to properly adjust bullet size, when using li:before?

Tags: html, css, list, margin, font-size

I'm using the following method in order to reduce the space between the bullet and the `<li>` item. it's working cross browser even on IE8.

Only problem is that If I'm trying to modify the size with the font-size parameter, as in this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ddzdngp/), you can see it's not a good solution.

CSS:

```
.list li:before { 
 content:"•";  
 margin-right:4px;
}
.list {
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    letter-spacing:-0.03em;
}
.list li {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="list">
        <li>How to Increase</li>
        <li>The bullet size</li>
      </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following CSS instruction to your `.list li:before`:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

See updated [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ddzdngp/1/)

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, you could take a screenshot of the bullet in the desired size, and use

```
list-style-image: url(path/to/image.png)
```

Comment: Now it appears a bit too much in the bottom, not exactly in the center, also, it still causes a wide margin problem between the two lines

Comment: You won't be able to get rid of the spacing, as this is caused by the "white area" around the bullets because of the increased font size (maximum font size in the text will determine the height of the line).
The bullet seems centred fine in Chrome.  But I'll amend the answer shortly with a different solution.

Comment: I'd rather not to use an image, it would make the client download another file, also in that case the :before property wouldn't be necessary, wouldn't it? I'm also using chrome and it doesn't seem so centered to me. anyway, that spacing problem is a major one, I thought maybe there's a way to make that character larger rather then use `font-size` :/

Comment: Actually... that can be done. I "solved" that part adding `line-height: 0.5` to the `li:before`, check: http://jsfiddle.net/3ddzdngp/2/. 0.5 might not be the perfect value, but you can fiddle around with that.

Comment: looks much better now, though especially on firefox and IE the bullet is way too much close to the bottom of the character rather than the middle, maybe there's a way to align it numerically rather than with `: middle`? ; also, looking again at the `•` character, at bigger sizes it's not rounded enough.. looks too narrow. couldn't find a different one though, maybe there's a solution for that as well?